# attempting to wget a python file leaves me with a file full of html

Tags: ubuntu, wget

the other day I needed to get a python file, which was hosted on a url (the actual url is not publicly available, so I'm just making a url up as an example)

So the file was available at a url similar to this:

```
https://platform.MyUni.dk/pluginfile.php/275570/course/section/131710/app.py
```

I wanted to try to use `wget` to get the file, so I just went straight ahead and tried it

```
wget https://platform.MyUni.dk/pluginfile.php/275570/course/section/131710/app.py
```

This did get the file, which correctly is a python file. But if I then look into the file, then it looks like this:

```
ask@Garsy:~/Notes/AdvancedSec$ cat app.py 
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html  dir="ltr" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>learnIT
```

Full of HTML. This really is a bit strange to me.
If I paste the link into my browser, then I get the option to download the file, and this works as it should.

How does all this html end up inside this file? and what can I do about it?

Answer (score -1):

The web server put it there so that the file pretty-prints in a web browser.

This is the actual web page.     https://platform.MyUni.dk/pluginfile.php

This is the file that is actually presented to you.

```
75570/course/section/131710/app.py
```

Look for the `raw` version of the file.

Otherwise, use a text editor to modify the file that you have now.

Comment: hmm I'm a little confused, i'm aware that the base url is the webpage. Should the raw file be hosted somewhere on the same system or how?

Comment: `Should the raw file be hosted somewhere` ... not necessarily ... it is up to the owner of the website to decide if raw files are available for download ... ask them

Comment: ah okay, so likely there is no flag that I can put on `ẁget` in order to get it to work?

Comment: why would you say that it is likely? ... that is an invalid assumption ... it is unknown ... there is a difference